# How to navigate to next tab in Razor pages after submitting first form

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

Is there anyway to navigate to next tab after submitting form in first tab in asp.net razor pages.
Currently im using return page() ,which will load first form.

Comment: Try RedirectToPage Method

Comment: hi,Should i pass my tab id inside the RedirectToPage()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there anyway to navigate to next tab after submitting form in first tab in asp.net razor pages.

It seems that you are using Bootstrap navigation tabs in your Razor pages. To achieve the above requirement, you can try the following approaches.

***Approach 1:*** store active tab info in [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) while user click the submit button, then you can activate specific tab based on stored active tab info via JavaScript, like below.

```
<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">

    <!-- STAFF DETAILS -->
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="StaffDetails">
        <br />
        <form method="post" asp-page-handler="InsertStaffDetails">
            Staff Details Partial Here
            @*<partial name="_StaffDetails" />*@
            <div style="float:right">
                <input type='submit' class='btn btn-success' value='Save' onclick="setNextActiveTabFunc('Biodata')"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <!-- BIODATA -->
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="Biodata">
        <br />
        <form method="post" asp-page-handler="InsertBioData">
            Bio Data Partial Here
            @*<partial name="_BioData" />*@
            <div style="float:right">
                <input type='submit' class='btn btn-success' value='Save' onclick="setNextActiveTabFunc('EduQualification')" />
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>

    <!-- EDUCATIONAL QUALIFICATION -->
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="EduQualification">
        <br />
        <form method="post" asp-page-handler="InsertEduDetails">
            Edu Details Partial Here
            @*<partial name="_EduQualification" />*@
            <div style="float:right">
                <input type='submit' class='btn btn-success' value='Save' onclick="setNextActiveTabFunc('Assets')" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    @*do same on other submit button*@
```

JS code

```
<script>
    function setNextActiveTabFunc(atab) {
        localStorage.setItem("activeTab", atab);
    }

    $(function () {
        var active_tab = localStorage.getItem("activeTab");

        //remove localStorage item 

        //localStorage.removeItem("activeTab");

        if (active_tab != "" && active_tab != null) {          
            $('#wizard a[href="#' + active_tab+'"]').tab('show');
        } else {
            $('#wizard a[href="#StaffDetails"]').tab('show');
        }
       
    })
</script>
```

***Approach 2:*** Can achieve same by checking handler name through QueryString, then dynamically set active tab on client side.

```
$(function () {
    var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    var pre_handler = urlParams.get('handler');
    switch (pre_handler) {
        case "InsertStaffDetails":
            //console.log("InsertStaffDetails");
            $('#wizard a[href="#Biodata"]').tab('show');
            break;
        case "InsertBioData":
            $('#wizard a[href="#EduQualification"]').tab('show');
            break;
        case "InsertEduDetails":
            $('#wizard a[href="#Assets"]').tab('show');
            break;
        //...
        //code for other tabs
        //..
        default: $('#wizard a[href="#StaffDetails"]').tab('show');
    }
       
})
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: Hi Fei Han,Thank you so much for the response. Its working fine,now my problem is when it goes to the Biodata tab,the selectlist in biodata form is not prepopulating.Could you please help me to figure out that.

Comment: `the selectlist in biodata form is not prepopulating` For this issue, I suggest that you can create a new thread to give detailed description about it, so that we can give further discussion in that thread.

Answer (score 1):

You can overrride your form submit with Jquery and after submit you can change tab with jquery.

```
 $("#yourFormId").submit(function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
       var post_url = $(this).attr("action"); //get form action url
        var request_method = $(this).attr("method"); //get form GET/POST method
        var form_data = $(this).serialize(); //Encode form elements for submission
        $.ajax({
            url: post_url,
            type: request_method,
            data: form_data
        }).done(function (response) { //
          // switch tab here 
         
        });
  });
```